# Using variable in Oracle Connection Sql Query

Tags: oracle, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to use variable in a SQL query but failed. What it the way to do this ?

```
 var SicilNumvber = SessionCurrentUser.EMPNO;
                    string query = "select * from crm_visible_v where ownerid in (select sicilno from personel.pkim_kutlama@netdb_1.europe.nortel.com where cikis_tarihi is null start with sicilno = :SicilNumvber   connect by prior sicilno = amir)";
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The success query is as below: 
Thanks for your helps;

```
string query = "select * from crm_visible_v where ownerid in (select sicilno from personel.pkim_kutlama@netdb_1.europe.nortel.com where cikis_tarihi is null start with sicilno ='"+SicilNumvber+"' connect by prior sicilno = amir)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please concatenate the fixed string with the variable part as I have done below

```
     string query := 'select * from crm_visible_v where ownerid in (select sicilno 
     from personel.pkim_kutlama@netdb_1.europe.nortel.com where cikis_tarihi is null    
     start with sicilno ='||SicilNumvber||' connect by prior sicilno = ''''amir'';
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it did not work. Actually, double quotation mark was faulty, i have also with single Quotation mark but it did not work.